# Updated to 15.10 and now VMware workstation 11 will not start

Tags: networking, kernel, vmware

I ran into this problem after upgrading to ubuntu 15.10. 
When I start vmware it pops up saying that it need to compile several modules into the running kernel.

It failed with a error message saying that it was unable to start services.

After starting it from the terminal I got some more information.
I am running on a fully updated ubuntu 15.10
and are using VMware Workstation 11.1.2 build-2780323

```
In file included from include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only/bridge.c:51:
include/linux/pci_ids.h:2252:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only/bridge.c:50:0:
/tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only/bridge.c: In function ‘VNetBridgeUp’:
/tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only/vmnetInt.h:81:40: error: too few arguments to function ‘sk_alloc’
 #   define compat_sk_alloc(_bri, _pri) sk_alloc(&init_net, \
                                        ^
/tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only/bridge.c:952:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘compat_sk_alloc’
    bridge->sk = compat_sk_alloc(bridge, GFP_ATOMIC);
                 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only/compat_sock.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only/bridge.c:35:
include/net/sock.h:1515:14: note: declared here
 struct sock *sk_alloc(struct net *net, int family, gfp_t priority,
              ^
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only/bridge.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only/bridge.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-6ABO6Y/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Blocking file system                                                done
   Virtual ethernet                                                   failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux testpc-cue 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `uname -a`

Comment: VMWare 11 does require several patches - you can find information in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/704020/283721)